# ¿Como cargar datos en un Fragment Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Esta es mi Activity

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el ASynkTask ejecute el postExcute le quiero pasar un array de objetos al fragment y que estos carguen en el.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Receta s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        tvNombreRecetaVer.setText(s.getNombre());
        tvDescripcionRecetasVer.setText(s.getDescripcion());
        tvComensalesVerReceta.setText(String.valueOf(s.getComensales()));
        tvTiempoVerReceta.setText(String.valueOf(s.getTiempo()+ " min"));
        tvDificultadVerReceta.setText(s.getDificultad());

        Glide.with(VerRecetasActivity.this).load(s.getImagen()).into(iVImagenRecetaVer);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de `onPostExecute()` puedes enviar el array de objetos mediante un bundle, de esta forma puedes realizar la carga del Fragment y enviar el array de objetos.

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putSerializable("array_objetos", listaObjetos);
 MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment)
                                .commit();
```

dentro del Fragment obtendrìas los valores de esta forma:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ArrayList arrayObjetos = new ArrayList();
  Bundle bundle = getArguments();
  if (bundle != null) {
      arrayObjetos =  bundle.getParcelableArrayList("array_objetos");
  }

}
```